# MS Access: Subform requery required to be run twice

Tags: forms, ms-access, listbox

Summary of Problem

I have a main-form/subform combination where the EmployeeList subform has a  dataview of employees which is linked to another employee details subform that displays among other things a listbox that runs a query displays all the training realting to the employee based on a combo box control value on the same employee details form call cbHighLevelRole.

The problem is that the training listbox is only updated on the second mouse click in the EmployeeList subform even though I have the requery code attached to the on-click event of the dataview subform.

Additonal Information

So the process flow is as follows.

The problem I think is that the listbox query which is

```
SELECT tblHighLevelRole.[HL User Role], tblTrainingModule.TrainingModule
FROM tblHighLevelRole INNER JOIN tblTrainingModule ON tblHighLevelRole.[HL User Role] = tblTrainingModule.[HL User Role]
WHERE (((tblHighLevelRole.[HL User Role])=[Forms]![frmMain]![frmEmployeeDetails].[Form]![**cbHighLevelRole**]));
```

references a highlevelrole combo box which I think maybe getting updated after the listbox requery. I am just unsure as to the order that things are being updated. This would explain why when I press the same user in the employeelist subform, the listbox displays the correct information. If I simply cycle through all the employees the listbox is always one entry behind.

What I have tried. I have tried adding to a number of events. The obvious one was to perform a listbox requery on the highlevelrole combobox afterupdate event but that did not work.

Edited Format.

Comment: Today I had a little more time to work on this issue. If a place a pause in the on-click event, the training listbox successfully updates so this problem is definitely that when the query in the listbox executes it uses the older cbHighLevelRole value. So it seams that the listbox query is executing before the combo box query which is nested in that query. But why?

Comment: instead of using the on-click event of the subform, try using the on-change event of the listbox.  This would cause your re-query to run only when a value is actually changed, which is also more efficient then running everytime someone clicks in your subform.

Comment: Hello Gene. Listboxes do not have an on change event. They do have an after update event but this is not being triggered. I tried using an on-change event on the role field which is what the query is using as a criteria but that too does not get triggered even though I can see the control value change.